# Materialize CSS Select Multiple - How to Limited the Number of Selections without jQuery

Tags: javascript, css, select, materialize

This is my first time working with Materialzie CSS and hopefully I made a good choice of a lightweight css framework. The newest version 1.0.0 does not require jQuery as a dependency and so I've just been initializing Materialize with:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var instances = M.AutoInit();
});
```

My issue is trying to limit the number of options that a user can select using a select dropdown. I have seen several examples that reference jQuery but none that use the Materialize native js. Here is my drop down code:

```
<form>
<div class="input-field">
<select name="test" id="seltest" multiple>
<option value="" disabled >Choose your option</option>
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
<option value="4">Option 4</option>
<option value="5">Option 5</option>
<option value="6">Option 6</option>
</select>
<label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
</div>
</form>
```

So what is the easiest way to hook into the select and limit the number of options that a user can select? This is mainly a client / UI issue since I will also have server code to validate the number of selections on the backend. But there must be a graceful way to unselect an option if the user tries to select more than what is allowed. All using materialize.js and not jQuery.

Thanks so much and love learning this new css framework.

Comment: Hmm. This is not supported out of the box, but I'll take a look at how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help

```js
$('#seltest').material_select();

function selectbox(select) {
  var result = [];
  var options = select && select.options;
  var meterial_select = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var opt;

  for (var i = 0, iLen = options.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    opt = options[i];

    if (opt.selected) {
      result.push(opt.value || opt.text);
    }
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < options.length; j++) {
    (result.length >= 3 && !options[j].selected) ? options[j].disabled = true: options[j].disabled = false;
    (result.length >= 3 && !options[j].selected) ? meterial_select[j].classList.add("disabled"): meterial_select[j].classList.remove("disabled");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<form>
  <div class="input-field">
    <select name="test" id="seltest" onChange='selectbox(this)' multiple>
      <option value="" disabled>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
      <option value="4">Option 4</option>
      <option value="5">Option 5</option>
      <option value="6">Option 6</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

you.

Comment: This doesn't limit the amount of options that can be selected.

Comment: your looking for limited number option select otherwise don't allowed to select  right?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think Materialize changes the form select to ul or li items and it's not triggering the js. Here is a link to the above code so you can see that it doesn't work with materialize. https://jsfiddle.net/v631besj/4/

Comment: @vadivel Perfect! It works! One quick question. If I have several selects that I want to limit the number of choices how do I target the script to each of the different select elements? I tried replacing document.getElementsByTagName("li"); with getElementById("seltest").getElementsByTagName("li"); but that didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Can try this " var meterial_select = document.getElementsByClassName("multiple-select-dropdown")[0].getElementsByTagName("li"); "

Comment: Thanks! This does work but only if I also pass in the index as well as not specify the "multiple-select-dropdown" style. If I apply this style to the select then it only works for the first select but not the second. Do you know why it works like this? Here is a page with the working code: https://jsfiddle.net/fry1sojh/ Do you see any issues? Again, if I use the "multiple-select-dropdown" style in the page it stops working. Maybe something to do with materializecss?

Comment: Yes Ok will try